# Bonita Liferay integration no such bonitasoft session impl api sessionimpl

Tags: liferay, bonita

I have installed Liferay 6.1-CE-GA2 & then I deployed BonitaBPM portlet in liferay.

[Reference](http://www.bonitasoft.com/for-you-to-read/videos/integrate-bonita-bpm-liferay-portal)

I download BonitaBPM Community-7.3.2(All In One) and it is running on 8080.
Now I integrated Bonita with liferay(It running on 9090) it throwing an errors when I'm changing the Portal Setting>Authentication>Bonita.

**ERROR:**  com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbsdtractReflectionConverter$unknownFieldException:No Such filed org.bonitasoft.engine.session.impl.APISessionImpl.tenantName

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed suggestion posted here http://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/no-such-field-exception-when-trying-login-using-java-api ?

Please verify the compatibility of your BonitaBPM portlet and your Bonita installation